# AngularJs - Making beautiful Select Dropdown Box (without using Image)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ui-select

I have got an angular page, where I am using a dropdown with ng-Options to fetch and set value. All is working fine. However, I need to beautify this. I have found the select box cannot be directly beautified by CSS. I tried to use ui-select but adding  instead of  only is not fetching me desired results. Can someone help me out in achieving me same?

**SNIPPET:**

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.20.0/select.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.20.0/select.min.js"></script>

</head> 
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

<select ng-model="colors" ng-options="x.text for x in colors track by x.value"></select> 
<!-- <ui-select ng-model="colors" ng-options="x.text for x in colors track by x.value"></ui-select> Not Working--> 

<script>

//app declaration
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//controller declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){

    $scope.colors = [{value:1, text:"red"},{value:2, text:"green"},{value:3, text:"blue"}];
    $scope.colors.value = 1;
});

</script> 

</body> 
</html>
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

> Pls, help me get beautified select dropdown by ui-select or otherwise.

Comment: What do you mean by beautify?

Comment: do you want to change option CSS?

Comment: Yes can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your life will be simpler if you use the ng-repeat notation for the select instead of the ng-options. Then you have many choices to do what you want, but maybe the most flexible is using ng-style this way:

```
<select ng-model="colors">
    <option ng-repeat="x in colors track by x.value" ng-style="{ 'background-color' : x.text}">{{x.text}}</option>
</select>
```

If you want to do further "beautifying" to your select there're plenty of resources on internet talking about it. You should have to do using attribute rules:

```
select option[value="red"]{
    background-red: red;
    ...
}
```